# Relation between asymptotic expansion of the heat kernel and wave kernel.

Tags: spectral-theory, heat-equation, wave-equation, laplacian

**Question 1.**
It is known that the heat kernel $e^{-\Delta{t}}$ of a closed and compact manifold of $n$-dimension has an asymptotic expansion around $t=0$:
$$
\mathrm{tr}(e^{-\Delta{t}}) \sim (4\pi{t})^{-n/2}\mathrm{vol}(M)(a_0 + a_1 t + \cdots).
$$
Then the wave kernel $e^{-\sqrt{\Delta}t}$ has an asymptotic expansion around $t=0$?

**Question 2.**
If the wave kernel $e^{-\sqrt{\Delta}t}$ has an asymptotic expansion around $t=0$, then what is a relation between two asymptotic expansions?

---

My  intuition for the **question 1**.

The asymptotic expansion of the heat kernel is used to show the analytic continuation of the spectral zeta function:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\zeta_{\Delta}(s) &= \sum_{\lambda>0}\lambda^{-s} \\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \{ \mathcal{M}\sum_{\lambda}e^{-\lambda{t}} \}(s),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ runs over the spectrum of the Laplacian.

Also, the wave kernel can be related with the spectral zeta function as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\zeta_{\Delta}(s/2) &= \sum_{\lambda>0}\lambda^{-s} \\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \{ \mathcal{M}\sum_{\lambda}e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}{t}} \}(s).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since the spectral zeta function $\zeta_{\Delta}(s)$ is extended to a meromorphic function over the complex plane, the wave kernel $\mathrm{tr}(e^{-\sqrt{\Delta}{t}})$ has an asymptotic expansion around $t=0$ given by the poles of $\zeta_{\Delta}(s/2)\Gamma(s)$.

But i don't think it is enough for the answer to the **Question 1**.

Thank you for your time and effort to read this article!

Comment: Start with the Mellin inversion integral of $\zeta_\Delta(s/2)\Gamma(s)$ and shift the contour to the left, because $\zeta_\Delta(s/2)\Gamma(s) t^{-s}$ is rapidly decreasing on vertical lines the obtained integral is $O(t^K)$, and the difference between the two integrals is the sum of residues at half integers, sum of residues at simple and double poles thus of the form $\sum_{k \le 2K+n} (u_k+v_k \log t) t^{-n/2+k/2}$.

Comment: The key point is the rapidly decreasing claim : it follows from that $ \int_0^\infty (t^{n/2}tr(e^{-\Delta t})-1_{t < 1}\sum_{k=0}^K \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} t^k) t^{s-1}dt=\Gamma \zeta_\Delta(s+n/2)-\sum_{k=0}^K \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\frac{1}{s+k}$ is analytic on $ \Re(s) > -K$ and bounded on vertical strips, where $f(t) = t^{n/2}tr(e^{-\Delta t})$ which is rapidly decreasing, smooth on $t > 0$ and with a Taylor expansion at $t=0$ (I don't know how to prove the last claim, do you ?)

Comment: @reuns Thank you for your comments! They makes me clear what we need to know. (About the rapidly decreasing claim)